# Problems with using PDO to perform an advanced search query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the following code and all of the search functions work except for the title field. So I can search by genre, date, location etc... but not by title. When attempting to search by title nothing is returned at all. Can anyone help me with this?

Also, is there a more efficient way to count all the fields before limiting it for use in pagination later on?

```
$today = date("Y-m-d");
$query = "SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE Date >= '$today'";

$bind = Array();

if ($_GET["Title"] && $_GET["Title"] != "") {
    $query .= " and Title like %?%";
    $bind['Title'] = $_GET['Title'];
}
if ($_GET["Genre"] && $_GET["Genre"] != "") {
    $query .= " and Genre like %?%";
    $bind['Genre'] = $_GET['Genre'];
}
if ($_GET["Location"] && $_GET["Location"] != "") {
    $query .= " and Location like %?%";
    $bind['Location'] = $_GET['Location'];
}
if ($_GET["Date"] && $_GET["Date"] != "") {
    $query .= " and Date = %?%";
    $bind['Date'] = $_GET['Date'];
}

$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute($bind);
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$num = count($rows);

$query .= " ORDER BY Date LIMIT $limit, 9";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute($bind);
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

**Edit:** After everyone's help I thought I would post my now revised code for future reference. It turns out the other fields were not working, but instead due to the if statement all this was nested in the code simply wasn't being executed.

```
$today = date("Y-m-d");
$query = "SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE Date >= '$today'";
$countq = "SELECT count(*) FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE Date >= '$today'";

$bind = Array();

if ($_GET["Title"] && $_GET["Title"] != "") {
    $query .= " and Title like :title";
    $countq .= " and Title like :title";
    $bind[':title'] = "%{$_GET['Title']}%";
}
if ($_GET["Genre"] && $_GET["Genre"] != "") {
    $query .= " and Genre like :genre";
    $countq .= " and Genre like :genre";
    $bind[':genre'] = "%{$_GET['Genre']}%";
}
if ($_GET["Location"] && $_GET["Location"] != "") {
    $query .= " and Location like :loc";
    $countq .= " and Location like :loc";
    $bind[':loc'] = "%{$_GET['Location']}%";
}
if ($_GET["Date"] && $_GET["Date"] != "") {
    $query .= " and Date = :date";
    $countq .= " and Date = :date";
    $bind[':date'] = "{$_GET['Date']}";
}

$stmt = $db->prepare($countq);
$stmt->execute($bind);
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
$num = count($rows);

$query .= " ORDER BY Date LIMIT $limit, 9";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute($bind);
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: There are not any errors returned, that's why I am so confused.

Comment: If it is just when you use 'title' there may be an error with the column name.

Comment: When searching with `LIKE` statements you need to escape all instances of `%` and `_` in user input using `addcslashes`.

Comment: You don't need no special count query! Just have one query body and prefix it with different fieldsets before execution.

Comment: `$_GET["Date"]` is equal to `$_GET["Date"] != ""` in any way

Comment: And you need `isset($_GET[…])`, otherwise you'll get an 'undefined index' error message if a GET parameter is not present in the query string.

Answer (score 2):

> all of the search functions work

With the given query it is not true

From [PDO tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info):

> placeholders cannot represent an arbitrary part of the query, but a complete data literal only. **Neither part of literal**, nor whatever complex expression or a syntax keyword can be substituted with prepared statement.
>
> Prepare FULL literal first: $name = "%$name%"; and then bind it.

As for the "more" efficient method for pagination - yes, oh yes.
With your current way of counting data you don't actually need other queries. as you have ALL the data already and can paginate it as well.
But of course it will pollute all the memory soon. So, if you want to get a count of rows from database, get the very count: run the same query but instead of `SELECT *` make it `"SELECT count(*)`

> There are not any errors returned, that's why I am so confused

From PDO tag wiki again:

> It is essential to set `ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` as a connection option as it will let PDO throw exceptions on connection errors. And this mode is the only reliable way to handle PDO errors.

Comment: I have been catching errors, its just i re-typed my whole code thinking i might be missing something

Comment: Thank you for you're detailed responses though. The method you suggested of counting certainly looks a lot better!