# Selecting a LARGE list (with filters) and PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a large list of data (house listings) that needs to have the ability to be filtered by the user. min/max amount of bedrooms, min/max price range, suburbs, types of properties.

I have created an array with the filtering options however the query only works if ALL the options are selected. I need to have the ability for it to work it only one option is selected.

Any ideas on how I should go about this?

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT *, (SELECT MIN(FileName) as FileName 
                    FROM `images` 
                    WHERE `images`.`PropertyID` = `property`.`PropertyID` order by `images`.`id` asc) 
                    as FileName 
                    FROM `property`
                    INNER JOIN `features` ON `property`.`PropertyID` = `features`.`PropertyID`
                    WHERE `property`.`Active` = '1' AND `property`.`homelink` = '0'
                    AND `property`.`Suburb` =  :suburb
                    AND `features`.`Bedrooms` >=  :bedroom_min
                    AND `features`.`Bedrooms` <=  :bedroom_max
                    AND `property`.`Rent` >=  :price_min
                    AND `property`.`Rent` <=  :price_max
                    AND `property`.`PropertyType` =  :property_type
                    GROUP BY `property`.`propertyid`
                    ORDER BY `property`.`AdvHeading` = 'LEASED!' ASC, `property`.`rent` DESC");


$vars = array(suburb,bedroom_min,bedroom_max,price_min,price_max,property_type);
foreach($vars as $key) {
    ${$key} = (isset($_GET[$key]) === true) ? $_GET[$key] : '';
    $query->bindValue(':'.$key.'', ${$key}, PDO::PARAM_STR);    
}

try {
    $query->execute();

    $rows = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo '<pre>', print_r($rows, true), '</pre>';

} 
catch(PDOException $e){
    die($e->getMessage());  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create your query dynamically. Here is a [recent question where you can see an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15866185/problems-with-using-pdo-to-perform-an-advanced-search-query)

Note that you can't wrap it in a loop due to different comparison operators. Better make it manually one by one, like in the referenced question.

Comment: Oh my! Dont you hate when you get an answer and when you see it is so obvious! Thank you kindly, this will work perfectly